# c execute doesn't work

Tags: c, bash, exec

I try to execute a program with some arguments by a c-program. But it seems to doesn't work.
Here is the code in c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
                execl("tempo2","-gr fake","-f best.sim.par","-ndobs 30","-nobsd 1","-ha 12","-randha y","-start 57023","-end 60000","-rms 0.0012",NULL);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with gcc on Mint 17. When I run that c-program nothing happens.
In bash it works and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 10`;
do
    tempo2 -gr fake -f best.sim.par -ndobs 30 -nobsd 1 -ha 12 -randha y -start 57023 -end 60000 -rms 0.0012
done
```

Can anyone translate me the bash code into c or tell what I did wrong?
Thanks and happy hollydays

Comment: any reason to not use the bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use system() function instead of execl() to execute shell command

```
system("tempo2 -gr fake -f best.sim.par -ndobs 30 -nobsd 1 -ha 12 -randha y -start 57023 -end 60000 -rms 0.0012");
```

Comment: okay, that works thanks. I need to run the program tempo2 in a loop 10,000 times. This takes about 6 hours. I can run it by bash or c, whatever takes shorter. Q: is there a way in c to accelerate the process?

Comment: you can and use threads and and run this command with loop in another threads asynchronously, I don't think that it will improve performance but you may get better speed result.

Answer (score 1):

check the return code. according to the man page,

> The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.

i donnot have your program, but you need to specify the full path to "tempo2", or you will get errno 2 => no such file or directory.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `execl` is the path to the program to run. The second argument is the value that appears in that program's `argv[0]` and is often the same. Thus, you should put `"tempo2"` **twice** in your argument list. Also, each space-separated word on the command line ahould be in a separate string. So instead of `"-gr fake"`, you should use `"-gr","fake"`.

All told, your `execl` call should look like this:

```
execl("tempo2","tempo2","-gr","fake","-f","best.sim.par","-ndobs","30","-nobsd","1","-ha","12","-randha","y","-start","57023","-end","60000","-rms","0.0012",NULL);
```

Finally, one important thing about `execl`. It **replaces** the current process with the new program. Thus, even though it's in a loop, `tempo2` will only be run **once**. To do what you're trying to do, you need to use `fork` to create a child process to run each `execl`.

All told, you're probably better off using `system` as @SunDro suggested.